# Do signals need to be protected by a QMutex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, signals-slots, qthread

I am working on a GUI with PyQt5 and 2 QThreads that would use each their own signals plus a shared signal used to send error code back to the GUI. I know that QThreads are meant to be used with pyqtSignals, but are their behaviour with signals excepting you to emit a shared signal from two different threads? 
Also, would using a Qmutex on the shared signal ensure that the threads access it at the same time or is it useless when dealing with signals?

I wrote this sample code, which runs properly, but I am not sure to understand how the signals are dealt with:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread, QCoreApplication
import time
import sys


class Class2(QThread):
    def __init__(self, signal):
        super().__init__()
        self.signal2 = signal

    def run(self):
        self.signal2.emit("Class 2 signal emitted")


class Class1(QThread):
    def __init__(self, signal):
        super().__init__()
        self.signal1 = signal

    def run(self):
        self.signal1.emit("Class 1 signal emitted")


class Action(QObject):
    shared_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        class1 = Class1(self.shared_signal)
        class2 = Class2(self.shared_signal)
        self.shared_signal.connect(self.action)
        class1.start()
        class2.start()
        time.sleep(1)

    def action(self, buffer):
        print(buffer)


app = QCoreApplication([])
Action = Action()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signals themselves are thread-safe since their main task is to enqueue the information and a mutex is used for this.

```
                ┌----------------------┐
                |                      |
                |         QUEUE        |
                |                      |
                └----------------------┘
                  ▲ ▲ ... ▲   | |     |
                  | |     |   ▼ ▼ ... ▼
                   SIGNALS      SLOTS
```

What may not be thread-safe is the connection since it depends on the type of connection. I recommend you read [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads) to know what kind of connections are insecure (for example using `Qt::DirectConnection` between QObjects that live on different threads).

- [Threads and QObjects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html)
- [Synchronizing Threads](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html)
- [Reentrancy and Thread-Safety](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html)

---

In your case the connection is safe, on the other hand I see time.sleep unnecessary but that can cause the object to be destroyed before invoking the signal so a possible solution is:

```py
import sys


from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QCoreApplication, QObject, QThread


class Class2(QThread):
    def __init__(self, signal, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.signal2 = signal

    def run(self):
        self.signal2.emit("Class 2 signal emitted")


class Class1(QThread):
    def __init__(self, signal, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.signal1 = signal

    def run(self):
        self.signal1.emit("Class 1 signal emitted")


class Action(QObject):
    shared_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        class1 = Class1(self.shared_signal, self)
        class1.finished.connect(class1.deleteLater)

        class2 = Class2(self.shared_signal, self)
        class2.finished.connect(class2.deleteLater)

        self.shared_signal.connect(self.action)
        class1.start()
        class2.start()

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def action(self, buffer):
        print(buffer)


def main():

    app = QCoreApplication([])
    action = Action()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: First of all, thanks the doc was very helpful and also thanks for the edits you made. I need help understanding one of them actually, why do you add `parent=None`, `super().__init__(parent)` and passing the Action instance when creating the Thread intances? Thanks again!